# CSS Navigation bar auto height

Tags: html, css, menu, navigationbar

[image]

I want to set the second level of navigator to be auto height, change to a new line when too long.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Orgaizational Structure</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Mission&Vision</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 #aaa;

    background: #dddddd;
    height: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    float: left;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #dddddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 #aaa;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/U72Hm/

Comment: Your fiddle seems (in firefox at least) to display the height correctly, please can you explain more clearly what your issue is?

Comment: @Alfie The image shown is the current style, not the ideal one. In the ideal one, "Structure" should be in a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking but if you want your text to wrap to a new line, change `white-space:no-wrap;` to `white-space:normal` for `menu li a{...}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem. you can actually take that rule out all together. Most browsers default to white-space:normal.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this answer doesn't technically answer the question, there are some excellent resources for menu's here http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/ explaining why certain CSS decisions are made and for which browsers.